# How can I build a list of bytes from its specification in Coq

Tags: coq, proof, coq-tactic, formal-verification

I'm trying to build a list of bytes according to the specification I do have in my context (The specification is defined based on the conjunction of `nth_error` functions that determine a byte value at an index (or byte values in a range of indices). For example, see the below goal and the context.

```
a_len, b_len : nat
a : seq.seq byte
b : seq.seq byte
H : Datatypes.length a = a_len /\           (* the length of list I'd like to build *)
    Datatypes.length b = b_len /\           (* the length of another list concatenated at the end *)
    is_true (b_len + 4 <= a_len) /\         (* added after edit *)
    is_true (1 < b_len) /\                  (* added after edit *)
    nth_error a 0 = x00 /\                         (* the value of first byte is zero *)
    (forall i : nat,                               (* then we have a bunch of x01's *)
     is_true (0 < i) /\ is_true (i < a_len - b_len - 1) ->
     nth_error a i = Some x01) /\
    nth_error a (a_len - b_len - 1) = Some x00 /\  (* next byte is zero *)
    (forall j : nat,                               (* which ends with a list that is equal to b *)
     is_true (0 <= j) /\ is_true (j < b_len) ->
     nth_error a (a_len - b_len + j) = nth_error b j)
______________________________________(1/1)
a = [x00] ++ repeat x01 (a_len - b_len - 2) ++ [x00] ++ b
```

I have tried to use some existing lemma like `nth_error_split` which is defined as:

```
nth_error_split :
    forall [A : Type] (l : seq.seq A) (n : nat) [a : A],
    nth_error l n = Some a ->
    exists l1 l2 : seq.seq A,
      l = (l1 ++ (a :: l2)%SEQ)%list /\ Datatypes.length l1 = n
```

and define some lemma like this:

```
Lemma two_concats_equality1: 
    forall (lb1 lb1' lb2 lb2': list byte), 
           (lb1 ++ lb2) = (lb1' ++ lb2') /\ length lb1 = length lb1' -> lb1 = lb1' /\ lb2 = lb2'.
```

to build the list of bytes, `a`, from scratch using `nth_error_split` and carry information along using `two_concats_equality1` and do this multiple times till end. But no success yet. I couldn't even prove `two_concats_equality1` lemma (just assumed to be true for the time being).
I've got stuck right at the beginning of the byte repetition, `nth_error a i = Some x01`.

I'm wondering if this is a right approach to prove this goal. If not, please let me know what you would do.

Any comments would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**

As @Yves pointed out, I'm making the following edits:

1. Fixing the typo in the context. There is no variable `n`, it should be `a_len`.
2. I added two more constraints in the spec that describe the relations for `a_len` and `b_len`, avoiding the false statement mentioned.
3. Below, you can find a minimal reproducible example with the libraries imported.

---

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect ssrnat.
From Coq Require Import Lia.
Require Import Init.Byte Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations. 

Lemma build_from_spec : 
    forall (a_len b_len : nat) (a b : list byte),
    Datatypes.length a = a_len /\
    Datatypes.length b = b_len /\
    a_len >= b_len + 4 /\
    b_len >= 2 /\
    nth_error a 0 = Some x00 /\
    (forall i : nat, (0 < i) /\ (i < a_len - b_len - 1) ->
    nth_error a i = Some x01) /\
    nth_error a (a_len - b_len - 1) = Some x00 /\
    (forall j : nat, (0 <= j) /\ (j < b_len) ->
    nth_error a (a_len - b_len + j) = nth_error b j) 
    ->
    a = [x00] ++ repeat x01 (a_len - b_len - 2) ++ [x00] ++ b.
Proof.
Admitted.
```

Comment: Please make a minimal reproducible example, especially indicating which libraries you loaded.

Comment: Your goal contains a variable `n` that is not explained anywhere, should it be `i`?

Comment: Thank you, @Yves. I'll edit my question with: 1) a minimal reproducible example; 2) fixing the typo for `n` that should be `a_len`; and 3) fixing the false statement issue you pointed out in you answer below by adding the missing relations for `a_len` and `b_len`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was edited by the original poster, changing the statement.  The bottom part of this message is an answer to the original question.

To solve this problem, you need a theorem that does not (yet) exist in the library, and which I include here:

```
Lemma eq_from_nth_error {A : Type} (l1 l2 : list A) :
  (forall i, nth_error l1 i = nth_error l2 i) -> l1 = l2.
Proof.
elim: l1 l2 => [ | a l1 IH] [ | a' l2] //.
    by move=> abs; have := (abs 0).
  by move=> abs; have := (abs 0).
move=> cmp; congr (_ :: _).
  by have := (cmp 0) => /= [[]].
apply: IH=> i; exact (cmp i.+1).
Qed.
```

With this theorem, you can prove the equality by studying all possible indices `i` that you give as argument to `nth_error`.  So, you introduce your hypothesis, and then you apply this theorem and, you introduce `i`, and you look at  5 possible cases for `i`:

1. if `i = 0`,
2. if `0 < i < a_len - b_len - 1`
3. if `i = a_len - b_len - 1`
4. if `a_len - b_len - 1 < i < a_len`
5. if `a_len <= i`

In ssreflect style, these cases are introduced by writing

```
have [/eqP i_is_0 | i_is_not_0] := boolP(i == 0).

have [i_lt_border | is_larger] := boolP(i < a_len - b_len - 1).
```

and so on.  You will be able to complete the proof.  You made your life complicated because your statement is written using the mathematical components versions of arithmetic statements: (i < a_len) is a boolean expression that is not recognized by `lia`, so you need to perform a lot of conversions to make things work.  Here is an example problem.

```
Lemma arithmetic_difficulty i j : i + 3 < j - 2 -> i <= j.
Proof.
Fail lia.
rewrite -?(minusE, plusE).
move/ltP => i3j2.
apply/leP.
lia.
Qed.
```

So you see, I need to use rewrite theorem `minusE`, `plusE`, `ltP`, and `leP` to transform the "mathematical components" definitions of `+`, `-`, `<` and `<=` into traditional versions of these operators, before `lia` can solve the problem.  Normally, `lia` should be improved so that this kind of transformation will not be needed in later versions of Coq (I am using coq.8.12 and this trickery is still needed).

A previous version of the statement was false, and prompted me to produce the following counter example:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Section some_context.

Definition byte := nat.
Variables x00 x01 : byte.

Lemma Dan_problem : (forall (a_len b_len : nat)
(a b : seq byte)
(H : Datatypes.length a = a_len /\
    Datatypes.length b = b_len /\
    List.nth_error a 0 = Some x00 /\
    (forall i : nat,
    is_true (0 < i) /\ is_true (i < a_len - b_len - 1) ->
      List.nth_error a i = Some x01) /\
    List.nth_error a (a_len - b_len - 1) = Some x00 /\
    (forall j : nat,
      is_true (0 <= j) /\ is_true (j < b_len) ->
      List.nth_error a (a_len - b_len + j) = List.nth_error b j)),
a = [:: x00] ++ List.repeat x01 (a_len - b_len - 2) ++ [:: x00] ++ b) ->
   False.
Proof.
intros abs.
assert (cnd1 : forall i,  0 < i /\ i < 1 - 0 -1 ->
  List.nth_error [:: x00] i = Some x01).
  by move=> i [igt0 ilt0].
assert (cnd2 : forall j : nat,
          0 <= j /\ j < 0 ->
         List.nth_error [:: x00] (1 - 0 + j) = List.nth_error [::] j).
  by move=> j [jge0 glt0].
generalize (abs 1 0 (x00::nil) nil (conj erefl
    (conj erefl (conj erefl (conj cnd1 (conj erefl cnd2)))))).
by rewrite /=.
Qed.
```

This script mixes mathematical components style and vanilla coq style, this is bad taste.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed that issue. But regarding using `nth*`, I have to use `nth_error`. Do you think if it still can be proved using `nth_error`?

Comment: I just read the edited question.  This makes the answer obsolete.  I will try to edit so that new readers don't get too confused.

Comment: Please Dan, look at the new version of the answer.

Comment: Thank you, @Yves! I don't have much experince in using SSReflect tactics. I guess I need to read about it first to better understand your answer.

Comment: this is how far I got given my limited knowledge of SSReflect tactics: `Proof. rewrite -?(minusE, plusE). intros. destruct H as (HLenA & HLenB & HLenRel & HLenBLo & HA0 & HRep & HEnd & HB).` ...

Comment: ... `apply eq_from_nth_error. intros i. have [/eqP i_is_0 | i_is_not_0] := boolP(i == 0). rewrite i_is_0. simpl in HA0. simpl. apply HA0. have [i_lt_border | is_larger] := boolP(i < a_len - b_len - 1). unfold is_true in HRep. rewrite -?(rwP ltP) in HRep. rewrite -?(minusE) -?ltP in i_lt_border. rewrite <- lt0n in i_is_not_0. assert (HPrem := conj i_is_not_0 i_lt_border). apply HRep in HPrem. apply (rwP ltP) in i_is_not_0.`

Comment: and I get stuck at second case. @Yves, I'm wondering if I'm properly following your lead.

Comment: Note that `unfold is_true in HRep.` is useless, I suggest removing this line.  Also, I think the `rewrite -?(minusE, plusE)` as first command is clumsy and it may not remove all the instances you would want to get rid of.

Comment: So we agree that the second case is the one where `0 < i < a_len - b_len - 1`.  You are almost finished, and you have `HPrem : nth_error a i = Some "001"%byte`.   Rewrite with this hypothesis, and then use lemma `nth_error_app2`, its arithmetic condition should be solved by `simpl; lia`.  Then use lemma `nth_error_app1`.  For its arithmetic condition, you will need a lemma about the length of repeat, this lemma is called `repeat_length`.

Comment: for the arithmetic condition of `nth_error_app1`, after the rewrite with `repeat_length`, you still need to modify hypothesis `i_lt_border` so that it uses the arithmetic operator `lia` knows, instead of the ssreflect variant.  This can be done by `move/ltP: i_lt_border => i_lt_border.` and then `simpl; lia` finishes this arithmetic condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222890/discussion-between-yves-and-dan-johnson).